# MariaDB unable to drop column named "`"

Tags: sql, mariadb, create-table, mariadb-10.1

Not sure how this happened, but a column got created named: "`". (just the back tick). When I attempt to drop this column, I end up with a syntax error.

Outside of taking a SQL dump and fixing the dump in a text editor, Does anybody have a suggestion to fix this query?

```
ALTER TABLE tableName DROP COLUMN "`";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the inner backtick with another backtick, so:

`````
alter table tableName drop column ````;
`````